# EF Navigation Properties in WCF Data Contracts

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to learn some best practices of using WCF contracts. I have a POCO entity class as shown below:

```
public class Job : IOwnerEntity<int>, ILoggableEntity
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int JobtypeCodeID { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int JobStatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobUserAssignment> JobUsers { get; set; }

    public int OwnerEntityID
    {
        get
        {
            return JobID;
        }
        set
        {
            JobID = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I create the corresponding data contracts, is it recommended to include the navigation properties in the datacontract(JobUserAssignment and Customer here)..?  To elaborate, which of the following contracts is the recommended way?

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IJobService
{
    Job GetJob(int id);//Gets job + job.Customer + job.JobUsers
}
```

or

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IJobService
{
    Job GetJob(int id);//Gets onlyjob 
    Customer GetCustome(int jobid);
    JobUserAssignment[] GetUsers(int jobid);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always: *it depends*.

If you retrieve a `Job`, do you **always** (or almost always) also need the customer and the assignments for that job? Then use approach #1 which always returns everything.

If you only need the customer and the assignments once in a while (in only 10%, 20% of the cases) and if retrieving that information is extremely expensive / inefficient, then I'd use approach #2 to only load them when *really* needed.

Getting everything in a single call is **preferable** if you always need that information anyway - making your user call three methods to get everything, every time he needs something, is pointless.

But if that additional info is needed only sparingly, only in few cases - then there's no point in doing all the work every time you retrieve a `Job` - in that case, leave it up to the user to decide when he needs the additional info (or doesn't need it).

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to tie your service layer to your data model. The problem you have is as your data model evolves (new columns, validation etc), your service will require re-syncing with the consumers of the service.

Instead, separate the data model and have a different set of objects exposed at the WCF layer.

The example below has modified your version to have:

- A class to represent the table in the DB
- A class to represent the data sent from WCF

Here is the code for these classes:

```
// Data Layer ---------------------
// In namespace Company.Data.Models

public class Job : IOwnerEntity<int>, ILoggableEntity
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int JobtypeCodeID { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }

    /* ... others here .... */
}

// -----------------------------------

// Services Layer --------------------    
// In namespace Company.Services.Contracts
public interface IJobService 
{
   Company.Services.Contracts.Job GetJobBy(int id);
}

// In namespace Company.Services.Contracts
[DataContract]
public class Job
{
   [DataMember]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

From here, you exchange messages using the `Company.Services.Contracts` namespace. The reason is that if your DB has additional columns for a table (say a new  `JobCategory`) then any consumers will be unaffected.

```
// In namespace Company.Services.Impl

using Company.Data.Models;
using Company.Services.Contracts;

public class WcfJobService : IJobService
{
    public Company.Services.Contracts.Job GetJobBy(int id)
    {
        EFDataContext dc = new EFDataContext();
        Company.Data.Models.Job dc = dc.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(x=> s.JobID = id);

        if(dc == null) { return null; }

        return new Company.Services.Contracts.Job { ID = dc.JobID, Name = dc.JobName };
    }
}
```